# Apache Localhost downloading php instead of executing, but only for one folder

Tags: php, macos, apache

So, I have multiple sites symlinked in my /Sites directory on OSX, so they appear on my localhost/~username , with php and apache enabled. I recently imported another site to the folder, and when I try to navigate to an index.php file on localhost, my browser prompts me to download the file. When I try to navigate to a different *.php file in a different site, the page is served properly. Any clue what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem - turned out that I had a .htaccess file because the files are identical to the production copy, and the file was preventing me from viewing the pages normally. Deleting it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar once, try checking the folders permissions to see if they match the other files/folders in local host.